# Create a car sound with frequencies

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to create a car game in C#. I'm now trying to figure out a way to get some sounds into the game. For example, the acceleration sound of the car.

I recently tried to add a 5 second-sound of a real car accelerating, but I don't think its the right way to do it. Because then i have to start from the beginning all the time of the clip when i accelerate.

Is there maybe some way to work with frequencies? To send a frequency to the speakers and then just increase it when I accelerate (And to make it sound like a car)

I've heard about PWM, could that be something?

Comment: I am way against the current trend of people voting to close because they don't know the answer to a question.  "I don't know, so it must be a bad question.".  It *may* be off-topic, but it certainly IS a "real question".  Tip of the day: don't be a dick, try to be helpful

Comment: This is not a programming question. It's better suited to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question is a fine question but it has been crossposted: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22979/create-a-car-sound-with-frequencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this might be to mix some sounds together...

For example, if you had a series of sounds such as:

- Car Idling
- Car accelerating from 1st to 2nd, gear, etc
- Sound of the car downshifting / engine braking
- Sound of the car in each gear

You could just play different sounds at different times and cross-fade between them.  Perhaps you could even do some pitch adjustment during playback to correspond to the throttle.

I'm not sure how the pros do it (Grand Theft Auto, Grand Turismo), but that's the first thing that comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

When I need audio in my C# projects I always try to use [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/).

[NAudio Algorithm to play a sinewave whose frequency can be changed smoothly in real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008561/naudio-algorithm-to-play-a-sinewave-whose-frequency-can-be-changed-smoothly-in-r) (there's a [link to an algorithm](http://naudio.codeplex.com/discussions/268394?ProjectName=naudio) the author wrote in the body of the question)

http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2009/10/playback-of-sine-wave-in-naudio.html